# Textarea must overlap div without increasing div height

Tags: html, css

I have a table that displays a form with labels and input fields. What I am trying to do is to create a textbox that overlaps rows in the table without changing the rows height the textarea is in.

I want to do this because in the row are more input fields, and I want to contain the height of those other rows.

HTML:

```
      <table class="table">
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="form-row-1">
                    <!-- Column 1 row 1-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-1">
                        <form>
                            <label>Abonnement</label>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-1">
                        <form>
                            <input type="text" name="Abonnement">
                        </form>
                    </td>

                    <!-- Column 2 row 1 -->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-2">
                        <form>
                        <!-- Add input fields here to create labels -->
                        </form>
                    </td>
                     <td class="form-column column-content-2">
                        <form>
                        <!-- Add input fields here to create input/select fields -->
                        </form>
                    </td>

                    <!-- Column 3 row 1-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-3">
                        <form>
                            <label>Abonnementsstatus:</label>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                     <td class="form-column column-content-3">
                        <form>
                            <select name=" ">
                                <option value="niks">Non-actief</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="form-row-2">
                    <!-- Column 1 row 2-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-1">
                        <form>
                            <label>Omschrijving</label>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-1">
                        <form>
                            <textarea rows="1" cols="30" name="lastname" style="overflow-y:expand;"></textarea>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Column 2 row 2-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-2"></td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-2"></td>

                    <!-- Column 2 row 3-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-3">
                        <form>
                            <label>Frequentie:</label>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                     <td class="form-column column-content-3">
                        <form>
                            <select name=" ">
                                <option value="niks">Non-actief</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="form-row-3">
                    <!-- Column 3 row 1-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-1"></td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-1"></td>
                    <!-- Column 3 row 2-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-2"></td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-2"></td>

                    <!-- Column 3 row 3-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-3">
                        <form>
                            <label>Frequentiebereik:</label>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-3">
                        <form>
                            <select name=" ">
                                <option value="niks"></option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr class="form-row-4">
                    <!-- Column 4 row 1-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-1"></td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-1"></td>
                    <!-- Column 4 row 2-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-2"></td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-2"></td>

                    <!-- Column 4 row 3-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-3">
                        <form>
                            <label>Bet. voorwaarden:</label>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-3">
                        <form>
                            <select name=" ">
                                <option value="niks"></option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr class="form-row-5">
                    <!-- Column 5 row 1-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-1"></td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-1"></td>
                    <!-- Column 5 row 2-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-2"></td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-2"></td>

                    <!-- Column 5 row 3-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-3">
                        <form>
                            <label>Onze ref.:</label>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-3">
                        <form>
                            <select name=" ">
                                <option value="niks"></option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr class="form-row-6">
                    <!-- Column 6 row 1-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-1"></td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-1"></td>
                    <!-- Column 6 row 2-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-2"></td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-2"></td>

                    <!-- Column 6 row 3-->
                    <td class="form-column column-label-3">
                        <form>
                            <label>Referentie:</label>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="form-column column-content-3">
                        <form>
                            <input type="text">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- More table rows below-->

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
textarea {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    resize:vertical;    
}

select {
    vertical-align:baseline;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abayob/v3phnxgk/1/);

So if I drag my textarea down, the height of the row must stay the same.
Is that possible using CSS, HTML, JavaScript?

Comment: you need to use rwospan in the txt area `td` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Comment: @Mi-Creativity You said it, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/2d5swosn/1/)

```
<td class="form-column column-content-1" rowspan="5">
                    <form>
                        <textarea rows="1" cols="30" name="lastname" style="overflow-y:expand;"></textarea>
                    </form>
                </td>
```

Also add this to your CSS in the `textarea` rule:

```
max-height:120px;
```

so that it will never ruin your form design

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one sir:

```
textarea {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    resize:vertical;   
    position:fixed;
    width:167px;
}

select {
    vertical-align:baseline;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/v3phnxgk/5/)

**or**

```
textarea {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    resize:vertical;
    max-height:120px;
    width:167px;
}

select {
    vertical-align:baseline;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**DEMO UPDATED**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/v3phnxgk/6/)

Comment: For my question, this is exactly what I asked! Thank you.